# MySql Rolling sum issue

Tags: mysql

I want to do rolling sum of column. I have created following query

```
SET @FinancialIncremental:=0;
SELECT  j.ErrorCategory, 
        COUNT(IF(j.ErrorType = 'P',j.ErrorType,NULL)) AS Financial,
        COUNT(IF(j.ErrorType = 'NP',j.ErrorType,NULL)) AS Procedural,
        SUM(j.OverPaymentAmount) AS 'Financial Over Paid Amount ($)',       
        (
            SELECT
                @FinancialIncremental := @FinancialIncremental + q1.c
            FROM
            (   
                (SELECT
                COUNT(IF(ErrorType = 'P',ErrorType,NULL)) AS c
                FROM DemoScheme.TestTable WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND ErrorType IN ('P','NP')
                GROUP BY ErrorCategory) AS q1
            )
         ) AS 'Financial Incremental'
FROM DemoScheme.TestTable j WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND ErrorType IN ('P','NP')
GROUP BY ErrorCategory;
```

But It is giving me an error. It giving me an error on 'Financial Incremental' subquery

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have some repetitions in there which complicate things unnecessarily,try this query.You might also need to replace NULL with 0 when you add it.

```
 SET @FinancialIncremental:=0;
SELECT  j.ErrorCategory, 
        COUNT(IF(j.ErrorType = 'P',j.ErrorType,NULL)) AS Financial,
        COUNT(IF(j.ErrorType = 'NP',j.ErrorType,NULL)) AS Procedural,
        SUM(j.OverPaymentAmount) AS 'Financial Over Paid Amount ($)',       
        (@FinancialIncremental := @FinancialIncremental + COUNT(IF(j.ErrorType = 'P',j.ErrorType,0))
 AS 'Financial Incremental'
FROM DemoScheme.TestTable j WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND ErrorType IN ('P','NP')
GROUP BY ErrorCategory;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your query. And also change NULL with 0. It is giving same result like `Financial` result if rows in `Financial` column is like 1,1,1,5,1,4 And Expected result in `Financial Incremental` column is like 1,2,3,8,9,13 etc.

Comment: `@FinancialIncremental ` is not holding the previous added value.

Comment: @AjayPunekar Can we have a small sql fiddle?